# Finding molar mass of uranium fluoride using Graham’s law of diffusion

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, diffusion

#### Problem

> A sample of uranium fluoride is found to effuses at the rate of $\pu{17.7 mg/h}.$ Under comparable conditions, gaseous iodine effuses at the rate of $\pu{15.0 mg/h}.$ What is the molar mass of the uranium fluoride?

#### Answer

> $\pu{354 g mol^-1}$

#### My approach

Perhaps I’m still having issues with significant figures, but I am getting the wrong answer. I know to use Graham’s law of diffusion, which leaves me with:

$$\frac{\pu{17.7 mg h^-1}}{\pu{15.0 mg h^-1}} = \sqrt\frac{\pu{253.8 g mol^-1}}{x}$$

I get $x = \pu{181.70 g mol^-1}.$ I know that the molecular mass of uranium fluoride should be less than iodine, so the answer makes no sense to me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the molar mass of uranium hexafluoride.

Comment: Also check the *exact* wording of the problem, to see if the flow rates are correctly associated to the two gases.

Comment: I agree with both the above - UF6 is 352 g/mol, and you get that if you take 15/17.7 rather than the other way around.  Either you misread or they miswrote.  Smaller *is* faster; KE = 1/2 mv^2 is the same on average for all gas particles moving through a pore at a given temperature.

Answer (score 2):

**Graham's law of diffusion deals with the molar effusion rate rather than mass effusion rate.**

This can be confirmed by the description of [Graham's Law on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_law).

An excerpt from the aforementioned page,

> $$\frac{r_1}{r_2} = \sqrt{\frac{M_2}{M_1}}$$
>
> where:
> $r_1$ is the rate of effusion for the first gas (volume or amount per unit time)
> $r_2$ is the rate of effusion for the second gas
> $M_1$ is the molar mass of gas 1
> $M_2$ is the molar mass of gas 2

Now the mathematical part,

$$\begin{align}
r_{\ce{UF6}} &= \pu{17.7 mg/h} = \frac{\pu{17.7 mmol/h}}{M_{\ce{UF6}}} \\
r_{\ce{I2}} &= \pu{15 mg/h} = \frac{\pu{15 mmol/h}}{M_{\ce{I2}}}
\end{align}$$

By Graham's Law,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{r_{\ce{UF6}}}{r_{\ce{I2}}} &= \sqrt{\frac{M_{\ce{I2}}}{M_{\ce{UF6}}}} \\
\frac{17.7}{M_{\ce{UF6}}} \cdot \frac{M_{\ce{I2}}}{15} &= \sqrt{\frac{M_{\ce{I2}}}{M_{\ce{UF6}}}} \\
\frac{17.7}{15} &= \sqrt{\frac{M_{\ce{I2}}}{M_{\ce{UF6}}}} \cdot \frac{M_{\ce{UF6}}}{M_{\ce{I2}}} \\
\frac{17.7}{15} &= \sqrt{\frac{M_{\ce{UF6}}}{M_{\ce{I2}}}}\\
M_{\ce{UF6}} &= \left(\frac{17.7}{15}\right)^2 M_{\ce{I2}}\\
  &= \pu{353.39 g mol^-1}
\end{align}$$